# Specify which method to call

Tags: python

Consider this class:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self, name):
        return 'bar: ' + name

    def baz(self, name):
        return 'baz: ' + name
```

I need to tell code to run the `baz` method:

```
def run_a_method(method, name):
    f = Foo()
    f.method(name)

run_a_method('baz', 'Jeff Atwood')
```

This fails with the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'method'

What is the proper way to call the function on whatever class `f` is defined?

Comment: Methods are attributes, so `getattr(f, method)(name)`.

Comment: Thanks, Blender. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `f.method` is **completely unconnected** to the argument `method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define your class correctly - don't forget the `self` parameter:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, name):
        return 'bar: ' + name
    def baz(self, name):
        return 'baz: ' + name
```

Then, use `getattr()` to access an attribute by name:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> getattr(a, "baz")("Jeff Atwood")
'baz: Jeff Atwood'
```